# setting public property in a private function executed on initialization Javascript

Tags: javascript, constructor, private, public

I have an object with

```
myObj = function(){
    this.myPublicMember = null;
    function privateInitFunc(){
         this.myPublicMember = "blah blah test";
    }

    privateInitFunc()
}

myObj.prototype = {
    getPublicMember: function(){ console.log(this.myPublicMember) }
}
```

and I instantiate like:

```
 var a = new myObj();
 a.getPublicMember // logs Null!
```

How do I set a public property in a private function executed on initialization? I need the private initialization function because there are some other variables there that are obtained before setting the myPublicMember

Comment: The way you've written it looks odd. Maybe you can expand the example a bit to show why exactly you need that extra function - what parameters does it depend on? I probably would've put that function outside of the constructor scope, and then called `this.myPublicMember = initFunc();`

Comment: @bergi the public member is actually a sprite from the Phaser.js framework. In the initialization function I add children and modify that member so that upon initialization of my object, the public member is already a sprite with various children inside of it.

Comment: Ok, but what's the reason to put this in an extra functon instead of directly in the constructor? Is it called multiple times, possibly recursive or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the context when you call the function:

```
privateInitFunc.call(this)
```